# Access database multi line description

Tags: ms-access

I've seen this posted before, but am unable to find it.

I have several databases which have description lines spread across up to three records. I would like to do a query in access to have the record on one line. E.g.

```
Source data:

Location    staff    Date                  Time         Description

012            12       2014-07-18      0800            Line1 of desc
012            12       2014-07-18      0800            Line2 of desc
012            12       2014-07-18      0800            Line3 of desc
012            12       2014-07-18      0800            Line4 of desc
612            06       2014-07-19      0812           Something desc
```

I would like the database to appear like this:

```
Location    staff    Date                  Time         Description1.           Description2.        Description3   Description4
```

Any direction would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a crosstab query if there is a "line number" for each internal sequence of descriptions.

You would make that line number the column header and I think you can make MIN(Description) the value of the crosstab.  Then you would make Location, staff, Date and Time the row values of the crosstab.

If there is not an existing line number for the internal sequence then you have some additional preparatory queries to do.